# Get [Messages] values in InnoSetup's language file

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, pascal

I know I can easily get messages inside

```
[CustomMessages]
AdditionalIcons=blablabla
```

using this code:

```
ExpandConstant('{cm:AdditionalIcons}');
```

which gets the `AdditionalIcons` string message. However, how can I get messages inside this?

```
[Messages]
ButtonNext=huhu
ButtonInstall=bubu
```

What I need is to get the `ButtonNext`, `ButtonInstall` and other values, and it is NOT possible to get those values using code like this:

```
ExpandConstant('{cm:ButtonNext}');
```

How can I query those values?

### Related links

[Inno Setup Script tips](http://www.mirality.co.nz/inno/tips.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
SetupMessage(msgButtonNext);
```

In general, the name of the constant to use (in this case `msgButtonNext`) is msg + the name of the message (string concatination).

Comment: Hm. So there isn't any way to just use them without code, like you can use {cm:xxx} in the non-code parts of the installer?